# iis express - cant get ssl to work in visual studio 2015

Tags: ssl, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

Im trying to get my website to run under https but for some reason IIS express wont play ball.  I have SSL enabled set to true, anonymous authentication is disabled and ive pasted the https url into the project url section.  Whenever I start the app it runs under standard http.  Is there something im missing in the setings ?

Comment: What did you do exactly? There are always more settings to cover, https://blog.lextudio.com/jexus-manager-secrets-behind-visual-studio-iis-express-integration-834f88c8e8b

Comment: followed the instructions here https://dotnetcodr.com/2015/09/18/how-to-enable-ssl-for-a-net-project-in-visual-studio/  but it still runs under http

Answer (score 2):

Please see if this helps: http://codehotfix.com/enabling-ssl-with-iis-express-in-visual-studio-express-for-web/

Select the startup project and press F4 (the function key) this will open the property window.

To enable the SSL with in IIS Express, you have to just set “SSL Enabled = true” in the project properties.

Once you change the value, Visual Studio set in automatic the SSL URL, e.g., https://localhost:44301/

Copy SSL URL. Go to the Advance properties by pressing Alt+Enter, select the Web tab and set the Project URL with the same value of SSL URL, e.g., https://localhost:44301/

Now you have configured the default URL of the web application, we can run the site (F5 or CTRL + F5).PS: The first time you set the secure protocol on IIS Express, you will be prompted to install the certificate for SSL.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to change the Start URL in the Project settings (under the Web tab).

The article you followed assumes that it's not set to anything, but you may have set it previously, and it just needs updating to the https:// based URL.

Comment: I tried that but it made no difference it always starts up under http

Comment: @user2347338 I think you should update your question with some screenshots of your settings.